# How to use Socket in AC3 or other solution for using embedded flash without cross domain policy?

Tags: actionscript-3, xss

> How to use Socket in AC3 or other solution for using embedded flash without cross domain policy?

I would like to create a project that uses HTTP to post to some website's form by using embedded flash in a webpage. When I finished the project, I tried to embed on the local computer and that work fine but when I uploaded to a web server in the some domain and requested to some different domain it stopped working. I know that's the security of ac3 but I would like to use embedded flash.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately one of the main purposes of the cross domain policy is to prevent exactly what it sounds like you're trying to do.

Without requiring a cross domain policy to 'ok' the use of the website like this it would be possible to have a simple flash trojan which did a DDOS attack against a website from a bunch of machines.

If you're embedding flash it may be possible that AIR has some way to do what you want - but other than a cursory look I haven't used it.

Comment: air has the same sandbox limitations as flash .  I didn't understand who embeding should be different then loading a file , where are you trying to embed the file from ? a different domain or local machine ?